# How to animate bootstrap progress bar only on scroll with javascript / jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar, keyframe

I want to animate the bootstrap progress bar on scroll (also every time you scroll the animation should restart). Ive looked up solutions on stackoverflow, but when I apply them, nothing works, so the progress bar still 'moves' not on scroll but on page load. I would like to just do it with js/jquery and keyframes and without any library. If anyone has a tip, that would be great. Thanks!

```
https://jsfiddle.net/hdxv4hrp/
```

code:
html:

```
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div style="width: 400px; margin: 50px auto">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="max-width: 60%">
            <span class="title">60%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="width: 400px; margin: 50px auto">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="max-width: 10%">
            <span class="title">20%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 400px; margin: 50px auto">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="max-width: 90%">
            <span class="title">90%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.progress-bar {
    width: 0;
    animation: progress 1.5s ease-in-out forwards;
    .title {
        opacity: 0;
        animation: show 0.35s forwards ease-in-out 0.5s;
    }
}
@keyframes progress {
    from {
        width: 0;
    }
    to {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@keyframes show {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
```

js:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
        progress-bar.addClass("show");
    } else {
        progress-bar.removeClass("show");
    }
});
```

Comment: what is `progress-bar` that is confusing are you subtracting here or is it the class name

Comment: sorry!! Just saw this- its the classname! I updated my question.

Comment: even if it is a class name shouldn't it be like `$('.progress-bar').addClass("show")`

Answer (score 0):

See below i think this is what you want i have added some `css` properties to keep the progress bar on top fixed position so that you can track the progress and verify if it works correctly

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).scroll(function(event) {
    var topPos = $(this).scrollTop() + 100;
    var windowHeight = $(this).height();
    var docHeight = $(document).height();

    if (topPos >= $('#progress-1').position().top) {
      $('#progress-1 >.progress-bar').css({
          'max-width': '100%'
        })
        .attr('aria-valuenow', 100)
        .find('span.title').text('100%');
    } else if (topPos < $('#progress-1').position().top) {
      $('#progress-1 >.progress-bar').css({
          'max-width': '0%'
        })
        .attr('aria-valuenow', 0)
        .find('span.title').text('0%');
    }


    if (topPos >= $('#progress-2').position().top) {
      $('#progress-2 > .progress-bar').css({
          'max-width': '100%'
        })
        .attr('aria-valuenow', 100)
        .find('span.title').text('100%');
    } else {
      $('#progress-2 > .progress-bar').css({
          'max-width': '0%'
        })
        .attr('aria-valuenow', 0)
        .find('span.title').text('0%');
    }


    if (topPos >= $('#progress-3').position().top) {
      $('#progress-3 > .progress-bar').css({
          'max-width': '100%'
        })
        .attr('aria-valuenow', 100)
        .find('span.title').text('100%');
    } else {
      $('#progress-3 > .progress-bar').css({
          'max-width': '0%'
        })
        .attr('aria-valuenow', 0)
        .find('span.title').text('0%');
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.title {
  color: #000;
}

.image {
  background-image: url(http://unsplash.imgix.net/44/lSed5VXIQnOw7PMfB9ht_IMG_1642.jpg?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=660&q=75&w=1050);
  height: 400px;
}

.progress-bar {
  width: 0;
  animation: progress 1.5s ease-in-out forwards;
  .title {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: show 0.35s forwards ease-in-out 0.5s;
  }
}

@keyframes progress {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes show {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="spacer"></div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div style="width: 400px; margin: 50px auto">
  <div class="progress" id="progress-1">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="max-width: 0%">
      <span class="title">0%</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

<div style="width: 400px; margin: 50px auto">
  <div class="progress" id="progress-2">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="max-width: 0%">
      <span class="title">0%</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div style="width: 400px; margin: 50px auto">
  <div class="progress" id="progress-3">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="max-width: 0%">
      <span class="title">0%</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br
/><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

Comment: thanks a lot. So actually what I want is that the progress bar 'fills up' when you scroll to that bar, not fills up slep by step while I scroll (so pretty much like it does with my code on page load, with the difference that it should happen when I scroll to that div).

Comment: you want the progress bar to fill up as we scroll TO the progress bar? and where exactly on the page this progress bar should be ? because in your provided code there are several progres bars and its hard to assume which one you are talking about

Comment: I mean all progress bars, thats why I provided code for all. When you scroll down to first progress bar, only then should the first progress bar fill up, then when you continue to scroll down to the second progress bar, that progress bar should fill up and so on. But it should always fill up 'fast' like when you scrolled to the position of the bar, it should fill up right away and not like step by step

Comment: i just updated the code see now if that is what we talked about. now they fill up as the `scrollTop` equals the `top` position of the target progress bar, and then revert to 0 if we scroll up.

Comment: i added an `offset` of  `100` with `scrolltop` adjust it according to your needs

Comment: thank you, but its not really what I need. First-your code lets each progress bar fill up to 100% and thats wrong and then so when you look at the code I provided, thats how I want the progress bars to fill up (again with the only difference of filling up on scroll, not on page load). I was using the keyframes for that